# Cannot use href with routerLink at the same time as conditional attributes in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a button component in Angular, which has the following inputs; `internalLink` or `externalLink`.

I'm trying to implement the component to use the `href` attribute if a string is passed via `externalLink`, but use the `[routerLink]` directive is `externalLink` is passed. I do this by conditionally applying the attributes, as below.

**ButtonComponent Template:**

```
<a 
  class="btn"
  [href]="externalLink ? externalLink : null"
  [routerLink]="internalLink ? internalLink : null">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</a>
```

However, it doesn't work as I hoped. If `externalLink` is passed and `externalLink` is omitted, I expected the href value of the link to be the value of `externalLink`. However, it's coming through with a value of `"/"`

**Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-link-external-internal-inputs**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existing answer won't work due to the reuse of `<ng-content>`, although I agree with the concept of declaring a separate element for each link.

**Existing answer**

```html
<a class="btn" *ngIf="externalLink" [href]="externalLink"> 
  <ng-content></ng-content> 
</a>

<a class="btn" *ngIf="internalLink" [routerLink]="internalLink"> 
  <ng-content></ng-content> 
</a>
```

**Why it won't work**

This won't work because Angular will pick only the last `<ng-content>` to project to - *even if it's inside an* `*ngIf`. [I have noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60337459/5367916) that this also happens with `<router-outlet>`.

**The fix**

The solution is to only render `<ng-content>` once inside an `<ng-template>`, and then reference that `<ng-template>` from multiple `<ng-container>` declarations.

So the solution now becomes:

```html
<a 
  *ngIf="externalLink"
  class="btn"
  [href]="externalLink ? externalLink : null">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl"></ng-container>
</a>
<a 
  *ngIf="internalLink"
  class="btn"
  [routerLink]="internalLink ? internalLink : null">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl"></ng-container>
</a>
<ng-template #contentTpl><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
```

This is an extension to @Sumit Parakh's original answer. They suggested the solution of splitting the links, I merely corrected the usage of `<ng-content>`, which was too complex for a comment.

Fixed in this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-link-external-internal-inputs-fixed

Answer (score 1):

Why not just separate them in two statements?

```
<a class="btn" *ngIf="externalLink" [href]="externalLink"> <ng-content></ng-content> </a>


<a class="btn" *ngIf="internalLink" [routerLink]="internalLink"> <ng-content></ng-content> </a>
```

Comment: The duplicate `<ng-content>` won't work here - the first one will always be blank

Comment: That seems to break the <ng-content> part, do you know why? Are you okay to reproduce in my Stackblitz example above?

Answer (score -1):

Some workaround until angular community wake up from their dream: use a method where you can add the href attribute:

```
<a 
  class="btn"
  [routerLink]="defineHyperLink(internalLink,externalLink, linkElement)"
  #linkElement
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</a>
```

Then in your component define the method defineHyperLink as below:

```
defineHyperLink(internalLink,externalLink, linkElement: HTMLAnchorElement): any {
  if(internalLink) {
    return internalLink;
  } else {
    linkElement?.setAttribute('href', externalLink);
    return
  }
}
```